# Set Zone Action Policy

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-c++, windows-7

I'm trying to figure out how to use this.  I want to set a value in Zone3 1803 from 0 to 3.  There doesn't seem to be any documentation out there. This C++ Win7 and IE9.

```
HRESULT SetZoneActionPolicy(
  [in]  DWORD dwZone,
  [in]  DWORD dwAction,
  [in]  BYTE *pPolicy,
  [in]  DWORD cbPolicy,
  [in]  URLZONEREG urlZoneReg
);
```

Basically, I'm using `RegOpenKey` and `RegSetValueEX()` but the problem is that I have to restart explorer for it to see the changes. So I added this.

```
SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)_T("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3"));
```

Still not working, so was told to use iinetZoneManger

Comment: I tried this...but te problem is that explorer isn't reconizing the changes and I was told to use iinternetZoneManager.  Can't seem to find much though.

Comment: Ok, I tried pasting in my code but it won't fit.  Basically, I'm using RegOpenKey and RegSetValueEX() but the problem is that I have to restart explorer for it to see the changes. So I added this. SendNotifyMessage(HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)_T("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\Zones\\3")); Still not working, so  was told to use iinetZoneManger.

Comment: I've added that in. Hopefully that will bump the question up the list again and get the attention of someone who can answer. (I actually have no expertise in this area but sometimes try to help improve questions through editing. By the way, why is it a problem to have to restart IE? That might help potential answerers work out an appropriate solution.

Comment: Can't restart because the employee will be on the page and the code runs to change the setting depending on the webpage. Thank you.  I'm trying to use iinternetZoneManager but can't find anything useful.

Comment: I still think you need to add more information for someone to help you. I certainly can't. Start with what you are doing with iinetZoneManager and why that isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
    HRESULT hr;
    IInternetZoneManager *pZoneMgr;

    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_InternetZoneManager, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
        IID_IInternetZoneManager, (void**)&pZoneMgr);

    //https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms537179(v=vs.94)
    int policy = URLPOLICY_ALLOW;

    //http://distcomp.ru/www/vladimirv/inetsdk/inet0287.htm
    hr = pZoneMgr->SetZoneActionPolicy(URLZONE_INTERNET, URLACTION_SCRIPT_RUN, (BYTE*)&policy, sizeof(policy), URLZONEREG_HKCU);
```